# Spring 3.1 JSON date format

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using annotated Spring 3.1 MVC code  (spring-mvc) and when i send date object through the @RequestBody the date is showing up as numeric.
This is my controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class MyController {

    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class,
                  new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),true));
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/getdate", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Date getDate(@RequestParam("dt") Date dt, Model model) {
        // dt is properly constructed here..
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

When i pass in date, i am able to receive the date in the format.
But my browser displays date as numeric

```
1327682374011
```

How do i make it display date in the format I have registered for the webbinder?
I saw in some forum that I should use jackson mapper, but cant i alter the existing mapper?

Answer (score 47):

In order to override the default date formatting strategy of Jakson following are the step to follow:

1. Extend `JsonSerializer` to create a new class for handling date formatting
2. Override `serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)` function to format date in your desired format and write it back to generator instance (gen)
3. Annotate your date getter object to use your extended json serializer using `@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)`

Code:

```
//CustomDateSerializer class
public class CustomDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {    
    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws 
        IOException, JsonProcessingException {      

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = formatter.format(value);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);

    }
}


//date getter method
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
```

Source: http://blog.seyfi.net/2010/03/how-to-control-date-formatting-when.html

Comment: Thanks Waqas.  I was wondering how the default JSON Serializer in spring works as I dont have jackson jars in the classpath.  probably it doesnt use jackson.

Comment: @M.AtifRiaz User is not active since Oct 22 '12 at 18:27. :)

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively if you are using jackson and want an ISO-8601 date on all dates (not just those you annotate), you can disable the default of writing dates as timestamps.

```
<bean id="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
<bean id="jacksonSerializationConfig" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig" factory-bean="jacksonObjectMapper" factory-method="getSerializationConfig" />
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonSerializationConfig" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="disable" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value type="org.codehaus.jackson.map.SerializationConfig.Feature">WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then if you want to convert your dates into some other format than the default, you can do this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="jacksonSerializationConfig" />
    <property name="targetMethod" value="setDateFormat" />
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
          <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
            <constructor-arg value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"/>
          </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is a more standard way to configure this, using ISO8601 dates, which is what I would recommend for your API.

```
<!-- you can't call it objectMapper for some reason -->
<bean name="jacksonObjectMapper" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="featuresToDisable">
        <array>
            <util:constant static-field="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS"/>
        </array>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- setup spring MVC -->
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters register-defaults="true">
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="jacksonObjectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Here is additional documentation:

- [Jackson FAQ](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling)
- [Spring's Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean.html)