# Timestamp getting as long instead of date format

Tags: java, json, spring, timestamp

I have a one rest method from Spring3 which returns expected JSON response except date which is in timestamp.

In database date is stored as `2013-08-08 00:30:00`. Before sending response to the application, the date I am getting as `2013-08-08 00:30:00`. I have checked it in debug mode. But after complete execution of rest-service, I got the date in long format as `1375902000000`.

I want to return same timestamp format instead of long format.

I don't want to convert long timestamp to again date format at client side.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring 3.1 JSON date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038005/spring-3-1-json-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

By default it is serialized as `long` if you want to send it like `2013-08-08 00:30:00` you may try `asString()`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following to keep your desire date format:

1. Declare the bean property as String.
2. Format the date object according to your desire format, example yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss