# Jackson datetime not getting serialized. bad request

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I am using spring framework and working on REST web services. One of my rest service insert/updates the date time value stored in one of the column of the my MySQL database table. The type I am using is datetime. My JSON request looks like:

```
                 {
                    "userId": "1",
                     "dateOfBirth": "1987-02-06 15:53:12",      

                 }
```

Spring has been configured to use Jackson as message converter. dateOfBirth field in java object is of type java.util.Date. Problem I am facing is when I hit the rest service with the above json request, the request becomes Bad request. I think it is related to date time conversion, jackson is not able to covert it to a date object. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Was spring able to take the request and map it to an object, but then fails the database operation, or was spring/jackson event not able to map the request to an object?

Comment: Try using the ISO date format instead.

Comment: Set your logger to DEBUG and check.

Comment: @Ralph - I am getting bad request so it is failing before database operation.

Answer (score 1):

Can try creating customer serializer/deserailzer by extending JsonSerializer and JsonDeserializer classes, and then annotate the date field with them, see these 2 posts:

[How to deserialize JS date using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591967/jackson-date-deserialization)

[Spring 3.1 JSON date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038005/spring-3-1-json-date-format)